# Hide first column in generated HTML table

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have this script that generates an HTML table based on MySql table. I would like for it to hide the first column.

```
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);

    echo "<th id = 'tableheader'>{$field->name}</th>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "<tr><td id = 'line'></td id = 'line'><td id = 'line' ></td><td id = 'line' ></td><td id = 'line' ></td><td id = 'line' ></td></tr>";
// printing table rows

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td id = 'tabledata'>$cell</td>";
    echo "<td><form method='post' action='delete.php'><input type='hidden' name='id' value='{$row['0']}'/><input type='submit' value='Delete'/></form></td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

Comment: Don't there exist templating engines in PHP? Manual string concatenation is an awful way to create HTML source code.

Comment: can't you just not output it?

Comment: `id` attributes should be unique through a document.  You've got the same one in a loop, which is bad practice.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the column from sql? Since notice that you fetch the field name from sql.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with CSS:

```
th:first-child, td:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Pzf9Y/2/

Comment: Thank you, but this does not remove the table header.

Comment: @user1175551 Does `th:first-child` ring a bell? `:P`

Answer (score 2):

You may need to know about [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

**Example**

```
$array = array(
    'one',
    'two',
    'three',
    'four',
    'five',
);
array_shift($array); // Remove the first element of array

foreach($array as $data){
    echo 'I\'m number '.$data.'<br/>';
}
```

Output :

- I'm number two
- I'm number three
- I'm number four
- I'm number five

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I wanted. Thank you @Kristianto